# SQL query to search 3 date fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run a query against 3 different fields.  I want it to return all the accounts that meet the first range, bring back all accounts that meet the second range and same for the third.  I tried using `and` but get dates outside of the range.

```
select 
    *
from 
    Permits 
where 
    created between '1/1/2015' and '1/21/2015'  
    and updated between '1/1/2015' and '1/21/15'  
    and noResponseDateSet between '1/1/15' and '1/21/15' 
order by 
    alarmNo
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Use ISO standard date formats:

```
select created, updated, noResponseDateSet
From Permits
where created between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-21' and
      updated between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-21' and
      noResponseDateSet between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-21' ;
```

This should fix the problem, unless you have one combination of rather arcane international date settings.

Answer (score 0):

[CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) can do the dirty parsing work for you. It will accept `1/1/2015` or `01-01-2015` or most other combinations.

```
select *
From Permits
where created between CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/1/2015') and  CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/21/2015')
and updated between CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/1/2015') and CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/21/15')
and noResponseDateSet between CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/1/15') and CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/21/15')
order by alarmNo
```

Comment: Or, just using the correct date format in the query.  No offense intended, but this makes about as much sense as doing `Upper('a')` as opposed to just using `'A'`